# What books does the Hunger Games movie span?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-hunger-games

Before heading off to the movie later this month, I'd like to blitz through the book(s).  Does the movie adaptation of *[The Hunger Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunger_Games_%28film%29)* cover just the first book or multiple?

Comment: At the rate Hollywood is going, it's probably just half of the first book. If they can find a way to make 5 movies with 4 Twilight books, I'm sure they find a way to get 6 out of the 3 Hunger Games books. All in 3D of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are already four movies expected for The Hunger Games. According to IMDB, two of these are titled the same as the first two books, Hunger Games and Catching Fire, while the others remain untitled.

The first movie appears to cover the first book, though whether there is any dangling story content left off from the 1st or brought forward from the 2nd book, for pacing or drama, is not clearly indicated anywhere. However, the conspicuous absence of such discussion, even from critics and fans who have previewed the film, further suggests the first book and the first movie are intended to and likely do coincide neatly.

EDIT: Confirmed. The first movie covers the first book in it's entirety without any overlap. However, as folks point out in comments, there are a couple scenes in the movie that are informed by content expanded on in the second book.

Comment: Just a minor addition - while the movie is almost a scene-for-scene adaptation of the first book, it does have (a little) content from the second book thrown in, probably as a hook to lead up to the sequel.

Comment: Avner: Are you referring to the scene with Seneca? I can't really think of anything else.

Comment: The scene of the riot in District 11 is the only thing I noticed. The scene with Seneca isn't really in any of the books, his death is only alluded to.

Comment: Good points... I think D11 & Seneca's fate were expanded from 2nd book content.

Answer (score 2):

By the power of hindsight and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunger_Games_(film_series)#Films), the films were as follows, each spanning the book they were named for:

- *The Hunger Games* (2012)
- *The Hunger Games: Catching Fire* (2013)
- *The Hunger Games: Mockingjay – Part 1* (2014)
- *The Hunger Games: Mockingjay – Part 2* (2015)

A film adaptation of *The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes*, the prequel to the series, has been announced to be in development in April 2020.

Comment: (Answer made cw since this is now just a simple lookup).